# Opening ports in SELinux: How to give a daemon permission to listen on predefined port type?

Tags: centos, ftp, haproxy, selinux

This is a fairly generic SELinux question, but with a specific example. I'm still fairly new to SELinux, so am regularly fighting with it!

I'd like to know if I can set up a daemon (in this case `haproxy`) to listen on more ports than its default selinux policy allows. For instance, SMTP and FTP are a couple of services that might make sense to load balance or proxy, but aren't allowed by the default SELinux policy.

There's already a fairly good question and answer describing the ports that `haproxy` is allowed to listen on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363878/which-selinux-policies-apply-to-haproxy

What I'd like to do right now is allow haproxy to listen on FTP, and only FTP ports. There are already port types defining typical ports used by FTP:-

```
#> semanage port -l | grep ftp
ftp_data_port_t                tcp      20
ftp_port_t                     tcp      21, 989, 990
ftp_port_t                     udp      989, 990
tftp_port_t                    udp      69
```

However, how do I allow haproxy to listen on these ports?

A few suggestions I've seen online, all of which I'm not particularly fond of, for various reasons:-

- Put selinux in permissive mode (can't believe this was even suggested)
- Allow haproxy to listen on any port `setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any 1`. This is again a bit too permissive for my liking.
- The answer from the above linked question would be to add the ports I'm interested in, on one of the port types haproxy already has access to. OK, so I could add port 21 to the http ports (or commplex ports, etc.), but that seems to defeat the point of `ftp_port_t` already being defined.
- Create a new policy with `audit2allow`. What I dislike about this personally, is this requires a number of dependencies (okay, not a huge number), and then deploying on multiple load balancers would be a bit cumbersome.

Ideally, I'd just like to know if there's a command available (ideally without having to install anything additional), that gives a process type (in this case `haproxy_t`) permissions to listen on a specific port type (`ftp_port_t`). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this example could work `semanage port -m -t haproxy_t -p tcp 20` 20, 21 etc. Verifying with `semanage port -l | grep haproxy` shows custom ports included.